# What is the best way to store variables in a PHP website for multiple users working on multiple projects at the same time?

Tags: php, session

I'm creating a website for multiple users that each work on multiple projects.

Each project can be completed by going through a few steps (a few pages).

I need to be able to use information from each page on the next one. I do store everything in a database, so I could fetch it from there, but I was hoping I could store it in sessions instead and wouldn't need to include anything in the get parameters.

The session solution was working fine until I realized that people might start one project and then another one before they complete the first one, and that would mess things up.

I suppose I could have all projects in an array in $_SESSION['projects'] but then I'd also need to have a get parameter to know which one is being worked on.

I'm sure lots of people have created similar websites and might have better solutions than what I've proposed, so I'd love to get your input.
Also, I know Wordpress uses get parameters when creating posts, but that's not a multistep process. Looks like Stackoverflow uses the post id in the url when I edit the post, but again not a multistep process. Maybe that's beside the point.

Comment: Your existing solution sounds like the sensible one, to be honest. Store it in the database, and fetch it when needed. Is it giving you an actual problem to do that? That's what most applications do.

Comment: It's not really giving me a problem doing that. It's just that I'm doing this for someone outside my organization for the first time, so I don't want to overlook anything or make things more complicated than I need to.

Comment: Sessions will definitely not improve things, especially if the user can have more than one tab open with different projects in it, and/or move between projects at will. And of course when you store things in the Session, data can get lost if they don't save at each step, too.

Comment: Please use URL parameters. I'm a multiple tab/window person and it is very, very, very frustrating when I run into session-based code that breaks this pattern.